# Looping Logistic Regression over DataFrame in Python

Tags: pandas, numpy, loops, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am stuck on where I am going wrong with this loop to perform Logistic Regression on a dataframe with 25 features.

When I reshape it giving the error :
"ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[-12.36677125 -12.91946925 -12.89317629 -13.16951215 -12.20588875
-12.44694704 -12.71370778 -12.69351738 -12.89451587 -12.0776727
-12.63723271 -13.39461116 -12.52027792].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."

```
peptides = ['AYSLFSYNTQGR','IVLGQEQDSYGGK','EQLTPLIK','SPELQAEAK','SPELQAEAK','ALVQQMEQLR','SGVQQLIQYYQDQK','VVVHPDYR','GFVVAGPSR','CLCACPFK','VVEESELAR','FCDMPVFENSR','GYSIFSYATK',
'EPGCGCCSVCAR',
'LIQGAPTIR',
'YYLQGAK',
'ALGHLDLSGNR',
'DLLLPQPDLR',
'GPLQLER',
'IISIMDEK',
'LQDAEIAR',
'QINDYVEK',
'SVLGQLGITK',
'ADLSGITGAR',
'EQLSLLDR']
```

That is the list of peptides I would like to interate over. They should be the columns titles to X_train.

```
LR_scores = []
logit_roc_auc =[]
y_pred = []
acc_score = []

for peptide in peptides:
    model=LogisticRegression()
    model.fit(X_train[peptide], y_train)
    score = model.score(X_test[peptide], y_test)
    y_pred=model.predict(X_test[peptide])
    acc_score = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    LR_scores.append(peptide,acc_score)
    
    #Classification Report
    print (classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
    
    #Confusion Matrix
    cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)
    print(cnf_matrix)
    
    #ROC_AUC Curves
    y_predict_proba = model.predict_proba(X_test[peptide])
    probabilities = np.array(y_predict_proba)[:, 1]
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, probabilities, pos_label=1)
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    logit_roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, model.predict(X_test[peptide]))
```

Any help is appreciated.

[Screenshot of Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HXIR.png)

[This loop works with different input lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfXV1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X is expected to be a 2D array while fitting the model, and y as a 1D array.

X_train[peptide] returns a series which is a 1D array. You can either -

```
X_train[peptide].shape
#Output  = (nrows,)
```

You can do this -

```
X_train[[peptide]].shape
#Output = (nrows,1)
```

OR

```
X_train[peptide].to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)
#Output = (nrows,1)
```

---

This should work -

In case there is another error, then there is more than one issue with the code. Please post that error in the comments as well.

```
for peptide in peptides:
    model=LogisticRegression()
    model.fit(X_train[[peptide]], y_train)
    score = model.score(X_test[[peptide]], y_test)
    y_pred=model.predict(X_test[[peptide]])
    acc_score = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    LR_scores.append(peptide,acc_score)
    
    #Classification Report
    print (classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
    
    #Confusion Matrix
    cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)
    print(cnf_matrix)
    
    #ROC_AUC Curves
    y_predict_proba = model.predict_proba(X_test[[peptide]])
    probabilities = np.array(y_predict_proba)[:, 1]
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, probabilities, pos_label=1)
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    logit_roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, model.predict(X_test[[peptide]]))
```

Comment: I have tried that, but I end up with this error:: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [26, 13]

Comment: does this work? you are using multiple functions that use a 2D train data, and 1D y data. please make sure you are making these changes in ALL of them

Comment: I have tried all of these without success. Most recently, was the middle one which produced this error: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[13.  1.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: I have only applied these changes to the X_train or X_test values

Comment: I am using this loop but the input list is a combination of peptides made with    "combos = list(combinations(X_train.columns,4))".   I am then using " for combo in combos" with the code working fine. I not sure what is happening.

Comment: ya correct, y_test, y_train, y_pred all need to have the shape (n,) , X_train, X_test need to be (n,1) in your specific case.

Comment: I added the other codet that is working as a screenshot.
 This is above it in the jupyter notebook

Comment: you are saying that when you take the [peptides] list as a list of more than 1 element (using combinations) the code works? Thats what i am saying too.. a `[peptide]` where the list is that of a single peptide (1 column) is a 1D array. while the `[peptide]` where the list of peptides is more than 1 columns is a 2D array automatically.

Comment: yes, the combination function is creating lists that would have multiple features in it. Here I am trying to test one feature at a time.

Comment: please use the code that i have posted in my answer.